# Using acl for a python command line tool

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a command line tool and i need to add acl to execute commands.  I use python 2.7x and have no clue on what is a best practices libary.

I see libs such as pylibacl and miracle-acl but dont know which is known to be best practice.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Change the acl and revert?

Comment: Personally I find it easier to call `icacls` as an external program, but I couldn't say if that is best practice - it will be inefficient if you have to call it numerous times.